# how to get a value from a input in django?

Tags: html, django

i'm trying to get a value from a input with django but dont work

python:

```
def add_entry(request):
        title = request.GET.get("title")
        content = request.GET.get("content")

        return render(request, "encyclopedia/add.html", {
            "title": title
            "content": content
        })
```

html:

```
<form action="{% url 'add_entry' %}" method="POST">
        <h1>Create new entry</h1>  
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <textarea name="title" id="textarea-title"></textarea>
        <h3>content</h3>
        <textarea name="content" id="textarea-content"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Create">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `method="…"` is `"POST"`, hence that means the data is encoded as payload in the request. You thus access the data through `request.POST`, not <s>`request.GET`</s>:

```
def add_entry(request):
    title = request.POST.get('title')
    content = request.POST.get('content')
    return render(request, 'encyclopedia/add.html', {
        'title': title
        'content': content
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

From the template form you are using a `POST` method on your form. So on Django view, you will retrieve it with the `request.POST.get('params') or request.POST['params'] where 'params' is the name`  and not `request.GET.get('params') or request.GET['params']` function

```
def add_entry(request):
   title = request.POST.get("title", "") # return "" is 'title' not available
   content = request.POST.get("content", "") 
   return render(request, "encyclopedia/add.html", {
        "title": title
        "content": content
   })
```